# Getting certain text inside HTML with Lua?

Tags: lua, pattern-matching

Currently I have this Lua script I made. For one it seems like it's a little inefficient, and the second thing is that I want no spaces in the result, except between the two words. Example: "Hello There" Thanks!

```
 st=[[<h1 class="notranslate" data-se="item-name">
                        Lookin Cool
                      </h1>]] 
    l,s=string.find(st,[[<h1 class="notranslate" data%-se="item%-name">]]) 
    n, w=string.find(string.sub(st, l), [[</h1>]]) x=string.sub(st, s, n) 
    r=string.gsub(x, "[%s]+", "")
    n=string.gsub(r, "%p", "")  print(n)
```

Comment: Please format your code better. Having more than one statement per line makes your code unreadable.

Comment: Also, your example code doesn't work; `st` isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Questions usually have at least one question mark in them. What are you actually asking for?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me but I'm not sure it's what you seek:

> `print(st:match(">%s*(.-)%s*<"))`.

In line with your solution, try

> `print(st:match('<h1 class="notranslate" data%-se="item%-name">%s*(.-)%s*<'))`